# custom segue that moves only part of content xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, animation, segue

I have seen a lot of tutorial but did not see any interesting me.  I want to make custom segue that moves only one view, not the whole page.

Something like this:

[image]

Top view is just poping without any animation.  But bottom view normally slides on bottom viewcontroler

I have tried:

`swift`

```
override func perform() {
    scale()
}
func scale(){
    let toViewController = self.destination
    let fromViewController = self.source

    let containerView = fromViewController.view.superview
    let originalCenter = fromViewController.view.center

    toViewController.view.viewWithTag(1)?.viewWithTag(2)?.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX:self.source.view.frame.width,y:0)
    toViewController.view.center = originalCenter

    containerView?.addSubview(toViewController.view)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay:0, options: .showHideTransitionViews ,animations:{
        toViewController.view.viewWithTag(1)?.viewWithTag(2)?.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    },completion:{success in fromViewController.present(toViewController,animated: false,completion: nil)})
}
```

If you do not understand, ask me and help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need this hierarchy

[image]

```
MainView
  -topView
  -containerView 
   -navigation
     -firstvc
     -secondvc
```

and set navigationBar to hidden in storyboard

[image]

Comment: i think something went wrong... i have this: https://imgur.com/r1kX5nR and as a result in app i see viewcontroller sticked to the top :https://imgur.com/UM0Xl4c

Comment: you need to drag a containerview and give height , left , right , bottom constraints then embed the constraint of the segue inside a navigation